# Cardinality of projection in the SPARQL 1.1 Recommendation

Tags: sparql

The official [SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/) defines projection as follows:

```
"Definition: Project
Let Ψ be a sequence of solution mappings and PV a set of variables.
For mapping μ, write Proj(μ, PV) to be the restriction of μ to variables in PV.
Project(Ψ, PV) = [ Proj(Ψ[μ], PV) | μ in Ψ ]
card[Project(Ψ, PV)](μ) = card[Ψ](μ)"
```

I cannot understand the definition of the cardinality of the resulting sequence `Project(Ψ, PV)`. I interpret `card[Project(Ψ, PV)](μ) = card[Ψ](μ)` as follows: For each solution mapping `μ` in the result of the projection `Project(Ψ, PV)`, the cardinality of `μ` in `Project(Ψ, PV)` is the cardinality of `μ` in `Ψ`, which I find odd since `μ` perhaps does not exist in `Ψ` when `PV`is only a part of the domain of the solution mappings occurring in `Ψ`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: μ are the elements of Ψ. `... | μ in Ψ `

Comment: Then why write card[Project(Ψ, PV)](μ) ? This means the cardinality of μ in Project(Ψ, PV)]

Comment: (last line in the definition)

Comment: Cardinality has to be defined. The same pattern of definition is used. Here, the cardinality in the projection is the same as the cardinality in the sequence before projection.

Comment: But the sequence resulting from the projection and the sequence before projection are different! How could the cardinality of arbitrary solution mappings be the same in both sequences, if the solution mappings occurring in either sequence may be different from the ones occurring the other one?!

Comment: So it should be something like  `card[Project(Ψ, PV)](μ) = sum card[Ψ](μ') for all μ' in Ψ such that μ = Proj(μ', PV)` ?

Comment: Yes, I think so!

Comment: Raised as an errata for SPARQL 1.2 to address. sparql-query/issues/80

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link?

Comment: Found the link https://github.com/w3c/sparql-query/issues/80

Comment: If you don't mind posting that with an answer so that we can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The card definition looks wrong.

It does not consider different solution mappings on the input projecting to the same solution mapping on the output.

A possible errata is:

```
card[Project(Ψ, PV)](μ) = sum card[Ψ](μ') for all μ' in Ψ such that μ = Proj(μ', PV)
```

and this has been passed to the working group for consideration.